# Dart DivElement

Tags: dart, dart-html

I want to insert my chart diagram inside the Div. In HTML I am having a div element like this

```
<div id="barchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

In dart I am creating a container like this.

```
Element createContainer() {
var e = new DivElement()
  ..style.height = '300px'
  ..style.maxWidth = '70%'
  ..style.marginBottom = '50px';
document.body.append(e);
return e;
}
```

The function createContainer is working fine as above... I want to draw the chart exactly inside "barchart_values" div. I tried as shown below but it is not working

```
Element createContainer() {
 var e = querySelector('barchart_values');
 document.body.append(e);
 return e;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to add the chart inside the div element 'barchart_values'

My Barchart Code

```
import 'package:modern_charts/modern_charts.dart';
BarChart chart;
DataTable table;  
table = new DataTable([
    ['Categories', 'Current', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3'],
    ['Value', 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ['', null, null, null, null],
  ]);



  var container1 = createContainer();

  var options = {
    'animation': {
      'onEnd': () {

      }
    },
    'series': {
      'labels': {'enabled': true}
    },
    'xAxis': {
      'crosshair': {'enabled': true},
      'labels': {'maxRotation': 90, 'minRotation': 0}
    },
    'yAxis': {'maxValue': 20, 'minInterval': 5},
    'title': {'text': 'Values'},
    'tooltip': {'valueFormatter': (value) => '$value core'}
  };

  chart = new BarChart(container1);
  chart.draw(table, options);
  //// end of chart creation
```

This is the error I am getting

NullError: method not found: 'toString' on null
Reason:null
STACKTRACE:
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null at BarChart.Chart$1

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Nothing in your code seems to be related to bar charts except the id string.

Comment: I added the chart coding

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/jolleekin/modern_charts/blob/master/example/web/example.dart ?

Comment: Yes using that only I created the chart it is working fine. The problem is Element createContainer() {
  var e = new DivElement()
    ..style.height = '400px'
//    ..style.width = '800px'
    ..style.maxWidth = '100%'
    ..style.marginBottom = '50px';
  document.body.append(e);
  return e;
}

Due to this function the chart gets appended in the bottom of the web page. Instead I want the chart here in this div 
<div id="barchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>

Comment: I tried var e = document.getElementById('barchart_values'); it did not worked. I tried var e = querySelector('barchart_values'); it did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your element

```
<div id="barchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

and `createContainer` as

```
Element createContainer() {
 return getElementById('barchart_values');
}
```

Comment: No it did not worked I tried return getElementById('barchart_values'); did not work
I tried return document.getElementById('barchart_values'); did not work
I tried return document.getElementById('#barchart_values'); did not work